# jQuery check if DIV (not window) started scrolling and addClass to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my "html" setted at overflow hidden (no scrollbar), but I have my contentarea div (where all the content is) that is scrollable and has a scrollbar...

What I'm trying to do is if user starts scrolling in the contentarea addClass (jquery) to another div.. if user scroll all the way to the top removeClass...

Here is the code I have that was working fine before I made the "html" overflow hidden..

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
    jQuery("#jQ").removeClass("scroll_active");
}
else {
    jQuery("#jQ").addClass("scroll_active");
}
});
```

I tried to put the contentarea id instead of window.. something like this:

```
jQuery(#contentarea).scroll(function() {
if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
    jQuery("#jQ").removeClass("scroll_active");
}
else {
    jQuery("#jQ").addClass("scroll_active");
}
});
```

but it still doesn't work...

http://jsfiddle.net/erxw5/

Can somebody give me a hand please, I tried everything I can already... Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `$()` instead of `jQuery()`. `jQuery()` works but it's unnecessary.
2. You should use `$('#contentarea')` or `jQuery('#contentarea')` instead of `jQuery(#contentarea)`, because you need quotes there. window is an object that exists. #contentarea is a string.

ALL MY FIXES TOGETHER: http://jsfiddle.net/mw3H8/1/

Comment: #contentarea is a variable in this context.

Comment: Variables can't start with # in javascript.

Comment: Patsy, what are you basing your statement on anyway?

Comment: sorry (#contentarea) I miss-typed this... the code is $("#contentarea").. but it still doesn't work.. :(

Comment: Can you add the following before your code to clean it up:
`var $contentArea = $("#contentArea");` 
`var $jQ = $("#jQ");`
Then, instead of using `jQuery(this)` on the second line, use `$contentArea.scrollTop()` and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Okay, try this: `$contentArea.scroll(function() {alert($contentArea.scrollTop());});` and see what happens (if anything) when you scroll inside the div.

Comment: already tried this, there is no alert... for both "window scroll" or "contentarea" scroll..

Comment: and from my thoughts... I see that this doesn't work because I have "overflow: hidden" for html...

Comment: but how other way I can hide the "PAGE" scrollbar and show it only for the contentarea..

Comment: `window` won't scroll if the overflow is hidden, but `$contentArea` should scroll if it has a visible overflow/scrollbar.

Are you sure `$contentArea` is the element that has a visible overflow and scrollbar?

Comment: Aaargh! Your problem is with the first line, before the code you included above... change `jQuery(window).load(function(){` to `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Then do everything else I suggested. :) Your code wasn't even running at all.

Comment: Another problem: Use `jQuery("#JQ")` and not `jQuery("#jQ")`. element IDs are case sensitive.

Comment: And once again, do not use jQuery(this). Please follow my instructions from the start.

Comment: I still don't understand why I can't use "$()".. if I use "$()" it won't work on site.. but if I use "jQuery()" .. it works...

Comment: Weird... `$()` works for me... is this on jsfiddle or on your own site? Maybe you have another variable called $? Maybe you're using a weird version of jQuery?

Comment: on my site only... in some files I see that there is "$()" and it works... in this file only "jQuery()" works... jquery version is 1.3.2 I think